# Why does this code need the volatile keyword?

Tags: c, volatile

I found this block of code [here](http://yosefk.com/blog/how-profilers-lie-the-cases-of-gprof-and-kcachegrind.html):

```
void work(int n) {
  volatile int i=0; //don't optimize away
  while(i++ < n);
}
void easy() { work(1000); }
void hard() { work(1000*1000*1000); }
int main() { easy(); hard(); }
```

...but I don't understand why it needs to use the volatile keyword for the integer `i`. (This is the entirety of the program.) I get that volatile enforces that the value of `i` is to be read from main memory, but in this case, since the value of `i` is getting updated by the program itself, why would the compiler think it was OK to do otherwise (and optimize away the while loop)?

Comment: Volatile does not force an access to main memory.  It only forces the compiler to include an instruction to read the value of the variable.  Since nothing else is writing the value, cache will never be invalidated so there are likely to be no main memory accesses of the variable.

Comment: @stark: It is likely not related to "main memory", but to stop the compiler from optimizing the the otherwise useless loop. Problem is a good compiler might still detect the variable cannot have a side-effect, as it is not known to the outer world.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because, without the `volatile` keyword, the compiler is free to observe that the loop does nothing and optimize it away to nothing. The value of `i` is lost after `work()` exits, so there is no observable effect of running the loop. (And even if `work()` were to expose that value, e.g. by returning `i`, the compiler could still potentially optimize the loop to a single assignment along the lines of `i = n`.)

With the `volatile` keyword in place, the compiler is required to retain all accesses to `i`, so the loop cannot be optimized away.

Comment: I see. I re-wrote the code to have i++ in the body of the while loop (i.e., trying to force it to "do something" in the while loop without changing the program) and the compiler (gcc -O) still optimizes it away. I don't know much about compilers so I'm not sure how/why it does this but it seems like an aggressive way to handle this. ETA: just saw your edit, this makes more sense now.

Comment: As the variable is an `auto` one and its address is nowhere passed, the compiler might still detect it cannot have a side-effect on the specific architecture, thus optimize the loop away. But afaik this is not done by current compilers, including gcc, which is known to very agressively optimise code.